# where to set the PO file for a plugin?

Tags: translation

I have a Cimy user plugin and I want to make translations and then force the Cimy user to read from my translation. Should I define the language in `wp-config.php` in the root folder?
I do not know where to change it?

I have `define('WPLANG', 'fa_IR');` in `wp-config.php` and it is reading from path

> \wp-content\languages

Should I change the fa_IR PO edit and just add the ones from Cimy user in the bottom of the WordPress fa_IR PO? or I should use separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the plugin should support translation.

If it is so, the directory where to put po/mo file is defined by plugin, usually they are in a directory `/langs` or `/languages` in plugin directory.

That directory is (should be) defined by plugin using [load_plugin_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain)

The plugin you are using has a subfolder `cimy-user-extra-fields/langs` where you can find the existing localization files.

**Your files (`cimy_uef-fa_IR.po` / `cimy_uef-fa_IR.mo`), should be putted in the same folder.**

To create these files you can use the software [PO Edit](http://www.poedit.net/) a powerful software, maybe not very easy to use.

If you already don't know it I suggest you the plugin [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/) a powerfull well written WP plugin that will help you trought the entire process of transalitng plugins, themes and wordpress itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, after I put them in langs it will read them automatically? if it will it is so cooool!

Comment: If files are created in right way, yes, it will. @Nickparsa

Comment: Hi, please consider updating the WP doc link to: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/

Answer (score 0):

All .po, .mo files should be within your plugin's folder, that is wp-content/plugins/myplugin.
For aesthetic purposes, save the .mo, .po files within the languages folder within myplugin.
Hope this helps

Comment: yes it has many files in langs and I tried to change one of them to my desired work the problem was that I didn't know if I name it correctly it will read it from the wp-config